Getting linker error, Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from"
Getting following error:
warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Reachability': framework 'Reachability' not found
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from

My Project Structure is as follows,
appModule
    appFeatures
        api
        apiImpl -> Reachibility pod added
    sharedFlavour
        common
        prod -> (point to common, export dependency, api project)
        qa  -> (oint to common, export dependency, api project)

I don't know how to add 2 different framework as one is "Reachiblity" pod, and 2 different export as both lie in different modules. Due to the use of "cocoapod" I have to add gradle plugin "cocoa-pod" in app, else simple export was working.
Repo: https://github.com/TheReprator/ExpenseManagmentBranch: error/internet
